# ¿Cómo acceder a JSON de laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo lo siguiente en mi controlador:

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    $id = $user->id;
    $accommodations = Accommodation::where("user_id", $id)->get();

    return  view('web/users/show', compact('user', 'accommodations'));
}
```

Cuando recibo la información en la vista, recibo dos tipos de JSON, uno es el siguiente:

```
{"id":2,"city_id":23,"first_name":"Maria","last_name":"González","email":"mariagonzalez@gmail.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}
```

a este puedo acceder facilmente con `{{ $accommodation->user->first_name }}`

Pero en el otro JSON no logro entrar, veo que este último tiene unos corchete "[]" al inicio y final del JSON:

```
[{"id":3,"user_id":1,"accommodation_id":5,"review":"Reviews test","stars":5,"created_at":"2018-11-22 22:14:01","updated_at":"2018-11-22 22:14:01"}]
```

He intentado con: `{{ $accommodation->review }}` con `{{ $accommodation->reviews }}` también con `{{ $accommodation->reviews->review }}` y no he podido

Estas son mis relaciones:

```
class Review extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'user_id', 'accommodation_id', 'review', 'stars' 
];

    public function accommodation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Accommodation::class);
} 

}
```

y esta otra:

```
class Accommodation extends Model
{

    public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
}
```

No sé como resolverlo, necesito acceder a los datos de la tabla reviews que está relacionada en MySql y también en el código como lo mostré anteriormente.

Muestra de los JSON:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando `get()` entonces te esta devolviendo tu informacion en un array, tendrias que pasar tu variable por un `foreach`, algo asi:

```
@foreach($accommodations as $accommodation)
   {{ $accomodation->review }}
@endforeach
```

Si quieres hacer uso de `{{ $accommodation->review }}` entonces tienes que usar `first()` en tu consulta, seria asi:

```
$accommodations = Accommodation::where("user_id", $id)->first();
```

Comment: acuerdate que en laravel es `{{ $accomodation->review }}` es decir te hace falta la sintáxis de las dobles llaves

Comment: Gracias por responder, bueno en mí post inicial no incluí el foreach pero en mí código si lo coloqué. Realmente necesito un array en el resultado por eso uso ->get();

Comment: Agregué una imagen en la descripción para que veas como se muestran los JSON, el primero (de la columna reviews, la que me da el problema) tiene unos corchetes, y la segunda  (de los usuarios) se muestra en un link y sin corchetes, allí accedo sin problemas al utilizar {{ $accommodation->user->first_name }}, pero si utilizo {{ $accomodation->reviews }} me muestra ese JSON y si quiero acceder a un elemento dentro de reviews no puedo, ejemplo: {{ $accomodation->reviews->review }} me muestra este error:  Property [review] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Sí uilizó $accommodations = Accommodation::where("user_id", $id)->first(); me trae solo un resultado y necesito un conjunto (array).

Comment: haz un `var_dump($accomodation->reviews)` para que confirmes si tus relaciones estan bien echas, talvez hay esta tu problema, porque por lo que veo en la imagen talve tendrias que hacer un `foreach($accomodation->reviews as $accomodation)` o algo parecido para acceder a tu coleccion